# shell script not working in crontab but works manually

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux

I am using crontab to open an image at every minute using a shell script. My script is working if I run it manually. But it is not executing in crontab. I have another script running well in crontab but not this one. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

My crontab line:

```
* * * * * /home/pi/Desktop/shellscript
```

My shell script:

```
#!bin/sh -x

PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:usr/sbin

/bin/sh /etc/pofile

export display=0.0

/usr/bin/eog -f /home/pi/Desktop/picture.jpg

sleep 100

killall eog
```

Comment: It's difficult to know what is the issue; could you follow the steps at [Debugging crontab jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4883069/6650102) and share the output in your post?

Comment: It's *export DISPLAY=:0.0*. Shell scripts are case-sensitive, as almost anything in UN*X. Mind the **:**, too. Also /etc/pofile isn't going to work, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check. Do an 'ls -la' on the script that is working and on the one that is not. You'll see something like '-rw-r--r--'. This is three sets of 'rwx' which means read/write/execute. The first set is for the owner of the file, the second for the group that owner is in, the third for everyone.
To run a script, chrontab needs 'x' execution rights. To add rights, you can say 'chmod a+x filename' which means 'changemode all+execute filename'. Not sure if that is your underlying problem, but that's a common issue with chrontab scripts not running.